# Comprobar si una columna existe en una tabla PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, oracle-12c

¡Buenos dias!

Necesito saber como comprobar si existe una columna en una tabla especifica. Estoy usando PLSQL en ORACLE 12c, a ser posible lo optimo sería poder usarlo en un IF THEN.

He intentado lo siguente:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tabla
    ADD (columna NUMBER(10));
```

Pero esto me devuelve un error si ya existe. y necesito que la cree solamente si no existe, y si no, que siga con la ejecucion del programa.

Tambien he intentado:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM DBA_CLU_COLUMNS
WHERE CLU_COLUMN_NAME = 'PRUEBA';
```

Pero tampoco me da el resultado que espero.

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder determinar si existe o no una columna en **ORACLE** puedes apoyarte en la vista del diccionario de datos llamada `DBA_TAB_COLS`, esta vista se compone de mucha información interesante, y sobre todo de la que tu necesitas, de esta vista necesitarias estos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este [Enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-857C32FD-AE30-4AB9-811B-AC3A7B91A04D.htm#REFRN23276) puedes consultar la documentacion oficial para tu version de **ORACLE 12c**

Ahora bien, ya con esta información en mano vamos a crear el procedimiento que necesitas. Utilizamos la vista del diccionario de datos y la integramos en un procedimiento de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE
      v_col_exists NUMBER 
    BEGIN
      SELECT count(*) INTO v_col_exists
        FROM DBA_TAB_COLS
        WHERE column_name = 'nombre_columna'
          AND table_name = 'nombre_tabla';

       IF (v_col_exists = 0) THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla ADD nombre_columna NUMBER(10)';
       ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La columna nombre_columna si existe');
      END IF;
    END;
    /
```